# Cauchy's definition of limit and Heine's definition of limit are equivalent..

Tags: calculus, continuity

Proof:
Cauchy -> Heine
$$ \forall x\in D\setminus \{a\}:\ |x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon \\ \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge n_0 :\ |a_n-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(a_n)-L|<\varepsilon \\ \lim_{n\to \infty}f(an)=L \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L  $$
Can somebody prove to other way: Heine-Cauchy?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ holds if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)$ holds **for all** sequences $\{a_n\}$ in the domain of $f$ that converge to $a$. It's false that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a_n) = L \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ for some fixed sequence $\{a_n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for a contradiction, that the Cauchy definition doesn't hold. Then, in particular, we can choose $\varepsilon>0$ and $a_n$ s.t. for all $\delta_n$ satisfying $0<|a_n-a|<\delta_n$, we have $|f(a_n)-L|\geq\varepsilon$

We want to construct the sequence $(a_n)$ so that it contradicts Heine i.e. we seek a sequence $(a_n)$ s.t. $a_n\to a$ but $f(a_n)\not\to L$. Given that we can choose any $\delta_n$ we like, can you see a choice that provides us a sequence with the desired properties?